# CONSULTA BDD MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola estoy intentado visualizar en una misma lista algunos campos de dos tablas diferentes. He conseguido hacer pero me duplica los datos. ¿Alguna ayuda como solucionarlo?

***Esta es la sentencia***

```
   SELECT p.fecha as "Fecha",v.jerarquia,v.nombre,v.apellido,en.nombre as 
   "Entidad",tc.nombre as "Contrato",p.n_contrato, d.dominio, d.n_f12, tv.nombre 
    FROM contrato p
    INNER JOIN tipo_contrato tc ON p.tipocontrato = tc.id_tipocontrato 
    INNER JOIN persona v ON p.personaid = v.idpersona 
    INNER JOIN entidad en ON p.entidadid = en.identidad
    INNER JOIN dominio d ON d.contratoid = d.contratoid
    INNER JOIN tipo_vehiculo tv ON d.id_tipovehiculo = tv.id_tipovehiculo
```

***y este es el resultado***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Estas son mis tablas.***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Esta es la relaciòn***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cual sería el resultado esperado?

Comment: Y donde se supone que duplica datos ?

Comment: Yo no veo datos duplicados. El dominio y el n_contrato son distintos de 2 a 2. No hay ninguna fila donde se repita el 100% de las columnas respecto a las demás. Quizá deberías añadir la clausula WHERE para filtrar más aún, o poner un DISTINCT (campo), según la necesidad que tengas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa tu consulta, fíjate en esta línea.

```
INNER JOIN dominio d ON d.contratoid = d.contratoid
```

Estas igualando la misma columna de la misma tabla así que no estás aplicando ninguna restricción aquí.

Comment: SELECT p.fecha as "Fecha",v.jerarquia,v.nombre,v.apellido,en.nombre as "Entidad",tc.nombre as "Contrato",p.n_contrato, d.dominio, d.n_f12, tv.nombre 
FROM contrato p
INNER JOIN tipo_contrato tc ON p.tipocontrato = tc.id_tipocontrato 
INNER JOIN persona v ON p.personaid = v.idpersona 
INNER JOIN entidad en ON p.entidadid = en.identidad
INNER JOIN dominio d ON p.idcontrato = d.contratoid
INNER JOIN tipo_vehiculo tv ON d.id_tipovehiculo = tv.id_tipovehiculo

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo. Gracias por la ayuda chicos !